# Logic Error PHP Looped Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, logic

This is a little complicated to explain, especially in the title - so here it is:

I'm making a PHP Array with 12 indexes, one for every month - each month will show the number of page views that were recorded in the month, to get the month, I'm using the current UNIX time and taking away 2629743 seconds (a month), each time the loop goes around, 2629743 more seconds are added - this should then generate the array such as (1, 4, 5, 9) 1 view in Jan, 4 views in Feb, etc.

If there are no views, I need it to be like (null, null, 9) so no views in Jan, none in Feb, 9 in March - but the indexes completely mess up and the views go in the wrong order.

The code for the loop:

```
$Month = 1; // Start with January
$MonthTimestamp = 2629743; // Start with the time of ONE month from current time
$ArrayTimeStamp = array();
while ($Month <= 12): // Go from January to February 

$Value1 = $now - $MonthTimestamp;
$ViewsThisMonth = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT SUM(Views) AS NumberFinalViews FROM BlogViews WHERE TimeRecord >= '$Value1' AND TimeRecord < '$now'"));
$ArrayTimeStamp[] = $ViewsThisMonth->NumberFinalViews;
$MonthTimestamp = $MonthTimestamp + 2629743;
$Month++;
endwhile;
```

To reiterate, the array needs to store each month of page views that are stored in a database, all page views are stored with a time stamp, these time stamps need to be seperated into the 12 months and then be put into the array.

4 views in Feb need to be in the second index, and the timestamp would be larger than January's timestamp but smaller than March.

All help appreciated!!

**Edit:** $now is the current UNIX time in seconds.

Comment: where $now comes from?

Comment: Any reason you're using the arcane `endwhile` instead of simply `while (...) { ... }`?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Why `null`? make it `0` `[0,0,9]`

Comment: 0 would work too. $now is the current UNIX time, should've noted.

Comment: There's no need for any of this. You can `SELECT SUM(Views)` from MySQL and `GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM TimeRecord)`, and MySQL will do all the work for you…

Comment: Timestamps aren't formatted. They're literally just UNIX seconds, i.e 4032948483 - don't understand what you're saying. I'm a noob with SQL. Can you post an example as an answer? @deceze

Answer (score 0):

1. You should ensure your columns containing time-related data are `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` columns. That will make time-based queries easier.
2. You can move the logic you're implementing in PHP into the query itself:

   ```
     SELECT SUM(Views) AS NumberFinalViews,
            EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM TimeRecord) AS YearMonth
       FROM BlogViews
      WHERE TimeRecord BETWEEN '$startMonth' AND '$endMonth'
   GROUP BY YearMonth
   ```

   If `TimeRecord` is just an integer representing a UNIX timestamp, you need to convert it:

   ```
    ...
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(TimeRecord)) AS YearMonth
   ```

   This returns you a result with the field `YearMonth` which has values like `201609` (September 2016), and the number of `Views` in that period, already pre-grouped. You just need to set the `$startMonth` and `$endMonth` as the absolute delimiters for the whole period you're querying, no need to do it for each month individually.

Comment: Would $startMonth and $endMonth be an entire year's value? So $startMonth would be the current time - a year, and end time would be the current time plus a year? It's the logic that is killing me.

Comment: Yes, they would be the entire year you're trying to query. Perhaps you can even simplify that to `WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(TimeRecord)) = 2016`, if you're interested in a whole calendar year.

Comment: Not a viable option - the query absolutely murdered the server speed

Comment: Yes, because you have to call `FROM_UNIXTIME` on every single value in the database. This would be solved by a) using `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` columns, which allow MySQL to work "natively" with the existing values, and b) using appropriate **indexes**.

Comment: Already using DATETIME columns and storing them as proper timestamps, TimeRecord is an index - still the same speed issue with only ONE row in the table... Here is the code [on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UHK6pKqA)

Comment: Wat? Slow with ***one row*** in the table? How is that even possible? How "slow" is "slow"? Sure your problem doesn't lie elsewhere?

Comment: Fixed the issue, but it's only getting ONE row from the Database and that value fills the entire array, i.e 333, 333, 333, 333 instead of 88, 333, 993, 493...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348799/array-assuming-data-unless-stated @deceze